# VBA getting value from object

Tags: vba, oop

I'm trying to get value from object in VBA, but it cinstantly says that

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

In watch this object looks something like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get it like this:

```
Visa.[Item 1](0).User_UPD
```

I know that problem is in my syntax. How should i call it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do that was like this:

```
Visa.Item(0).User_UPD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim k As Object        
    Set k = New PutTheNameOfTheObjectHere        
    Debug.Print k.Visa.items(1)(0)
    Debug.Print k.Visa.item(1)(0)

End Sub
```

And play a bit with the code, something should show up at the end :)